# How to remove OS X Extensions from System Preference?

Tags: macos, share-extension, finder-extension

In Mac OS X we have Extensions in System Preferences they are used for Finder & Share. I uninstall the apps but it still remains.

How can I remove it once the application is uninstalled?
There must be some settings in some file where it is stored, someone please help to know its location.

I am using Extensions on my App, but on uninstall it leaves the residue.